# Natural line width from absorption lines

Tags: observational-astronomy, spectroscopy, spectra, electromagnetic-spectrum

Emission lines have a certain natural width. Due to the uncertainty principle systems that spontaneously decay or produce radiation have a fundamental energy blur, and their radiation has a corresponding natural line width.

I am wondering how that phenomenon translates to absorption lines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The natural linewidth also causes absorption lines to be broadened in exactly the same way.

Usually, the natural linewidth is *far* narrower than the width caused by (i) Doppler broadening by thermal motions of the atoms/molecules, (ii) collisional broadening caused by interactions between atoms/molecules, (iii) the broadening imposed by the finite spectral resolution of the instrument being used to measure the spectrum.

Comment: Collisional broadening does not lead to a Gaussian profile but also a Lorentzian profile (effectively, it reduces the natural lifetime of the state). So it would not be distinguishable from natural broadening as such. See e.g.  http://www-star.st-and.ac.uk/~kw25/teaching/nebulae/lecture08_linewidths.pdf for more details

Comment: @Thomas agreed.